# How does mentions works in markdown files (*.md) or any other text?

Tags: javascript, node.js, markdown, node-modules, github-flavored-markdown

I'd to start a React/Next/Vue blog, doesn't matter for real, the only thing is important, that's it will be based on JavaScript framework, about cats

For example I have a DB with `cats`:

```js
ID    Name (<= unique)
 1   Kitty
 2   Catty
 N   .....
```

So I want to write in markdown some cool facts about my cats, like a blog article:

```
  fact_one.md

My cats are @Kitty and @Catty and they are awesome!
```

And then post it. Later, imagine that every cat has a personal page, and when it visits the page, it sees (doesn't matter how exactly) that this kitten has been mentioned in `fact #1`.

### The point:

**I am not asking, how exactly browser notifications works, event listeners and so.** I am asking about:

- For what exactly should I google/search/look for parsing user mentions in text via symbols like `@` (any Regexp pattern)?
- Using markdown in such case appropriate on not? Maybe there is better way?
- What `npm` module / maybe a blog article would you recommend for it?

For example I have take a look at [marked.js](https://github.com/markedjs/marked) and `GFM` but I am still not sure.

I mean, that if my blog become popular, it will a problem if every my article is stored as a raw `*.md` file, I guess I should store it in database. What's the best way to do it? I mean storing text as a field in markdown/html syntax, or store `raw *.md` as binary? But if I store my text in DB, how to control mentions? Or there is another way?

So every useful and helpful information will be appreciated and rewarded will up-voting.

Comment: It depends on the username format you want to use. If your usernames don't have spaces, you can just look for the username between `@` and the space after the `@`.

Comment: To be honest, tagging user is not a real problem, I derive a `slugName` for every cat, so there will be no spaces and so on. So each time when I write something like: `@Catty` it will be `@catty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex like  `\s@(\w+)` to match and capture the names.

At the time of saving a new post, or updating a post, in the database, you can extract the mentions and update them to a relationship between personal pages and posts with mentions.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I also thought about it, like checking `md` file every time on create/update for mentions.